# JUCE Vst3 not created after successful build

Tags: xcode, juce

I am trying to build a simple VST created with Projucer. In the Projucer Project settings,
Enable Plugin Copy Step is by default enabled, and VST3 binary location is correctly pointing to my default VST3 folder location on my Mac $(HOME)/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST3.
After saving settings and successfully building in Xcode, with my Build Scheme set to All, no Vst3 is created at the location. It does not work either when changing the scheme to vst3.

What did I miss in setting up my project?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered the same problem using macOS and Xcode. My problem was the following: the default build product was selected as the `VST3 manifest helper`([look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBPTh.png)).

You need to change the active build product to `VST3` or `all`.